# How can I move a frame?

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

Inside my page, I have a frame that loads another page. I am using this to detect if they want to move the frame around the screen:

```
private void Frame_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {

    }
}
```

How do I move the frame itself though? I have been trying to look for it and I cant seem to find the variables that control its position.

Answer (score 1):

Try positioning using the frame's margin:

```
AppFrame.Margin = new Thickness(Mouse.X, Mouse.Y, 0, 0);
```

---

Alternatively, *some* frames are able to be moved with their Left and Top variables.

```
frame.Left = Mouse.X; // or whatever
frame.Top = Mouse.Y; // or whatever
```

In order to move it proportionally to the mouse, record the mouse and frame's original positions when the mouse was first dragged, and referenced them when positioned:

```
frame.Left = originalFrameX + (Mouse.X - originalMouseX);
frame.Top = originalFrameY + (Mouse.Y - originalMouseY);
```

Comment: The issue is that frame doesn't have a Left or Top

    `Frame AppFrame = new Frame();
    AppFrame.Width = 1000;
    AppFrame.Height = 500;`

Comment: Then margin is probably how the frame is positioned. Ty this:
AppFrame.Margin = new Thickness(Mouse.X, Mouse.Y, 0, 0);